# What is sparsity in image processing?

Tags: image

I am new in image processing and I don't know the use of basic terms, I know the basic definition of sparsity, but can anyone please elaborate the definition in term of image processing?

Answer (score 5):

Well Sajid, I actually was doing image processing a few months ago, and I had found a website that gave me what I thought was the best definition of sparsity.

> Sparsity and density are terms used to describe the percentage of
>   cells in a database table that are not populated and populated,
>   respectively. The sum of the sparsity and  density should equal 100%.
>
> A table that is 10% dense has 10% of its cells populated with non-zero
>   values. It is therefore 90% sparse – meaning that 90% of its cells are
>   either not filled with data or are zeros.

I took this in the context of on/off for black and white image processing.  If many pixels were off, then the pixels were sparse.

Answer (score 4):

As The Obscure Question said, sparsity is when a vector or matrix is mostly zeros. To see a real world example of this, just look at the [wavelet transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet_transform), which is known to be sparse for any real-world image.

[image: wavelet]

(all the black values are 0)

Sparsity has powerful impacts. It can transform matrix multiplication of two NxN matrices, normally a `O(N^3)` operation, into an `O(k)` operation (with k non-zero elements). Why? Because it's a well-known fact that `for all x, x * 0 = 0`.

What does sparsity *mean*? In the problems I've been exposed to, it means similarity in some domain. For example, natural images are largely the same color in areas (the sky is blue, the grass is green, etc). If you take the wavelet transform of that natural image, the output is sparse through the recursive nature of the wavelet (well, at least recursive in the Haar wavelet).